# How to truncate a string given an expression using boost

Tags: c++, string, boost, boost-regex

I need to truncate a `string` after an underscore.
Example:-

```
std::wstring name = L"Steve_Smith";
trim_right_if(name, is_any_of(L"_"));
```

The trim_right_if is not working, the name remains the same after its execution.
Is there a way using `boost::regex` ?

Yes, i am trying not to use `find_first_of` and `substr`, which i know works.

Comment: What about `std::string::find` and `std::string::resize`?

Answer (score 0):

`trim_right_if()` is only if it's in the end of the string.
"Steve_Smith___"  ==>  "Steve_Smite"

what you want to do is `replace_all(name, L"_", L"")`;

Comment: replace_all only removes the underscore, the output is SteveSmith.I am actually trying to rename a file which has an underscore, for example test_doc.txt ==> test

Comment: @user1690041 - Ha, I didn't understand the question correctly... but it's good you found the answer.